# Finding specific table head using jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, html-table, head

Is there a method in jQuery to count across multiple table head classes 
( `<th class="entity7">Machine Names</th>` tag) until a table head with the value "Machine Names" is found? "Machine Names" is the value in the particular table head cell I need to count to. This will allow me to know which number column I want to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter()` for this:

```
var $th = $("#myTable th").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "Machine Names";
});
var columnNumber = $th.index();
```